Integrating $\int_{0}^{z_0} \int_{0}^{\rho_0} \tan^3\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right]d\rho\,dz$
I am a hobbyist math learner so forgive me if my question sound too obvious.
I am at a loss on how to solve this integral after unable to find the answer from wolfram and wiki:
$$\int_{0}^{z_0} \int_{0}^{\rho_0} \tan^3\left[a\left(c - \frac{\sqrt{\rho ^2+z^2}}{b}\right)\right]d\rho\,dz$$
Wolfram alpha does not seem to want to even render this after I hit calculate, in latex or words.
And the Wikipedia does not seem to have this either from my searches.
If someone could help me figure this out, it would be great.

EDIT:
$a,c$ are variables while $b$ is a constant.
And the coordinate system is cylindrical.

After translation and polar coordinates this is effectively $2\pi A\int r \tan^3 (a_0 r) dr$. You can study this integral on wolfram alpha

@fGDu94 do you have the link to the docs to wolfram where this integral is discussed?

@fGDu94 could you post this as an answer with the link to this from wolfram and the steps you took to reach that answer?

@fGDu94 I will glad accept your answer as the correct one if you are able to provide it with steps taken and links. I would like to wrap this question up. Thank you

Please do not answer in the comments, @fGDu94.

@YvesDaoust I took this from a physics problem. But computing this integral is a pure math problem for this question's sake. The variables inside the $\tan$ are for the retarded time https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retarded_time with $a$ being the frequency and $c$ being the time and $b$ being the speed of light, which is a constant.

I've posted my answer. A bit different from @fGDu94's.

@Mathaholic. As mentioned by Yves already in his comment, the problem can't be solved without specifying the area of integration, because the variables $x,y$ might reappear in the parametrization of the domain of integration.

@Abezhiko I have put in the domain of integration

@YvesDaoust I have put in the domain of integration

@MrChessR I have put in the domain of integration

@YvesDaoust The original coordinates are cylindrical. Let me update my question.

Now we're getting somewhere. $\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}=r$, but I don't remember how $d\rho,dz$ transforms to spherical coordinates.

@GerryMyerson Could it be $d\rho dz=rsinϕdrdϕ$??

@Mathaholic. No, one has $\mathrm{d}\rho\mathrm{d}z = r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\phi$ instead.

@YvesDaoust Would you or someone else post an answer to this please in light of the new information and comments?

@GerryMyerson Would you or someone else post an answer to this please in light of the new information and comments?

I used Python's numpy library to solve this integral as it is not doable analytically.
